# How to use multiple imageview in one xml file

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I am new to Android. In my project I need one XML with  50 imageview but now I am try to create two imageview but my project give error and halt. And when I use only one imageview then my project works fine. My XML file is:

activity_myCal.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MyCalendarActivity" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<ImageView android:id="@+id/eka_name"
    android:src="@drawable/pandava_eka"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ImageView android:id="@+id/eka_name1"
    android:src="@drawable/prabhu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my NotificationView.java:

```
package com.example.customcalendarandroid;
import java.io.File;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class NotificationView extends Activity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_calendar);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eka_name);
    } 
}
```

Where is the error?

Comment: Ok dou you know about grid view? i think you will not need to take 50 imgview it can solve by a single imageview

Comment: Do you want it like http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-6-ZzMZYQaBI/UREtyBo5SWI/AAAAAAAAAKs/KVkaCM_SjBM/s1600/Output1.jpg this?

Comment: please set the relativity/dependency of your views like `above and below` 
if you don't know as much about relative layout then you should try with the linear layout to take the `orientation`.

Comment: 50 ImageViews... just to make your app explode!!

Comment: Post your logcat Please

Comment: i need 50 images in res/drawable but on screen i want only one image at a time.should i use gridview or listview ?